# Where can I find a firing squad (for Time Takes Its Toll and A Forceful Rebuke)?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements, diablo-iii-wizard

Two Wizard Challenge achievements deal with projectiles: Time Takes Its Toll (slow 20 with one Slow Time) and A Forceful Rebuke (reflect 8 with one Wave of Force).

[image]

It seems like getting both with the help of the same friendly demons would be pretty easy, but I can't find any that are willing to shoot me that much; gangs are either too small or fire too slowly.  Where's a good place to get shot?

Comment: I don't know if their attack is considerd a projectile, but you can try with the succubi. You can find them in great numbers in Act 3, before fighting Cyadea.

Answer (score 7):

I got both of these achievements in Act II. The desert is full of wasps that shoot littler wasps, and these littler wasps count as projectiles.

Simply find a group of wasps, cast Slow Time, and stand in the center. Since each wasp fires volleys of 4, you should get the "slow 20 projectiles" in a matter of seconds. Afterwards, simply use wave of force to send them all flying for the second one.

Answer (score 2):

Act IV, End Boss. When you are fighting him the third time, again in the real world, he has an ability where he casts a stream of "fire / lightning at you." That stream isn't a beam, but many single projectiles.

I got the Time takes its toll achievement there. Don't know about forceful rebuke, since I didn't try to fling these projectiles back.

Or you can try to find a big group of these Moonclan Javeline Throwers in the first act. With enough hp/armor you might be able to pull enough of them to get these achievements.

Comment: My mate got the first achieve in Act 2 with the bugs that send groups of 4 projectiles. It isn't hard to find a few of them together, along with one or two of the fallen shamans helping out too.